# Using spine.js with haml

Tags: javascript, haml, template-engine, spine.js

currently I'm playing a little bit with spine.js
I have red the documentation about views and there they have shown an example with eco as templating engine.
Until now i don't really like the eco engine.
I would prefer to use haml as my templating engine.

Is there a way to add support for haml in spine.js?

Until now i tried to add https://github.com/uglyog/clientside-haml-js in my index.html and then i was able to compile haml templates, in my controller, to html.

But it is not possible to load the templates in the same way as it works wit the eco files.

So how can I integrate haml into spine.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a slug.js file to your application which includes the relevant stuff
You will find a more detailed solution here: https://groups.google.com/group/spinejs/browse_thread/thread/d951e77db33d084a

Answer (score 1):

Use [hem-haml-coffee](https://github.com/vojto/hem-haml-coffee).

I recently added jhaml support as an equivalent to jeco.